# OpenVPN connection - Multiple Tunnels

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, routing, openvpn

i have a system setup, mostly from reading posts and instructions.

My basic setup

multiple openvpn clients, e.g. macbook, android phone

dd-wrt router / firewall

ubuntu server as EXTERNAL openvpn server and openvpn tunnel to raspberry pi

raspberry pi as INTERNAL openvpn server and PIA client

i did a drawing as its easier to understand i think
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dbJjReDC4IE3WZ9h1AsYM7HXANgDeZHplA/view?usp=sharing

my problem

forget the raspberry pi tunnel for now. The tunnel is down.

I can connect into my home network, INTERNALLY and EXTERNALLY via openvpn from all my clients, browse the LAN and browse the internet and i get my ISP external IP when browsing

If i bring up the tunnel between the ubuntu server and raspberry pi, i can connect to the openvpn server INTERNALLY from all clients, browse the LAN and internet and i get the PIA external IP(from the pia tunnel on the  raspberrypi) when browsing. But I can no longer dial in to my server from outside my network. I just get 'Waiting for server'

if i drop the tunnel between the ubuntu server and the pi, i can get back in to my LAN from the outside...

What i would like to be able to do is

be able to dial in from outside, to my ubuntu server, this then has a tunnel to my raspberry pi which has a tunnel to PIA and then the internet. So the goal is, wherever i am, i can dial my home vpn, be able to access the LAN but also have the PIA external IP, not my home ISP IP. This already works when im inside my network, need it from outside

Here are my conf / misc files that i use split by server and server/client
https://github.com/bicklp/scripts/tree/master/help

Comment: If you're building mesh-like network then your best find is tinc. It's able to interconnect together in many ways, has a simple setup consisting of configuration file, private key and a set of hosts description files and it's able to create both tunnels and virtual LANs (ethernets with ARP inside). With virtual LAN, you will able to make one machine to be gateway and just setup a default route through it.

Answer (score 0):

Got it sorted.
I just needed to add the following to the server.conf file

multihome

that sorted everything out